# How do I add a button to activate Annyang JS?

Tags: javascript, annyang

Sorry for the noob question but my JS skills are extremely limited.
So I am implementing Annyang to my webpage. It loads with the page, but i would prefer to add a button to activate it. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script>
if (annyang) {
    // Let's define a command.
    var commands = {
        'hello': function() { 
            alert('Hello, You can now speak to navigate around this website. Try it now by saying "Contact"'); 
        },
        'goodbye': function() { 
            alert('Goodbye!');
        },
        'contact': function() { 
            window.location.href='../contact-us/'; 
        },
    };

    // Add our commands to annyang
    annyang.addCommands(commands);

    // Start listening.
    annyang.start();
}
</script>


<button class="btn btn-secondary-alt view-more" onclick="annyang.start();">SPEAK NOW</button>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `annyang.start()` in the script. That line already calls it when annyang is ready.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are asking but it looks like this should work. it is probably better to move the inline javascript to your script as well.

instead of onclick="annyang.start(); do something like:

```
// if you are not using jQuery
var annyangBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".annyang-btn");
annyangBtn.addEventListener("click", annyang.start(), false);
```